# Subscription message not being received in Qt

Tags: spring-boot, qt, stomp

I am testing a STOMP communication between a Spring Boot server and a Qt desktop program.
The server implementation looks as follows:

```
@Controller
class GreetingController {

     @MessageMapping("/hello")
     @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
     @Throws(Exception::class)
     fun greeting(@RequestBody message : HelloMessage) : Greeting  {
         Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
         return Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!")
     }
}
```

The Qt program looks as follows:

```
bool StompClient::sendFrame(std::shared_ptr<StompFrame> stompFrame) {
     if (!stompFrame->isBinaryBody()) {
         QString str = stompFrame->convertToQString();
         m_Socket.sendTextMessage(str);
         qDebug() << "Send stomp frame " << str;
         return true;
    }

    QByteArray ba = stompFrame->convertToByteArray();
    m_Socket.sendBinaryMessage(ba);
    return true;
 }

 std::shared_ptr<StompFrame> StompFrameCreator::createSubscribeFrame(const QString&   destination) {
     auto stompFrame = std::make_shared<StompFrame>();
     stompFrame->setCommand(StompFrame::HeaderTypes::SUBSCRIBE);
     stompFrame->addHeader("destination", destination);
     return stompFrame;
}

std::shared_ptr<StompFrame> StompFrameCreator::createSendTextFrame(const QString& destination, const QString& message) {
     auto stompFrame = std::make_shared<StompFrame>();
     stompFrame->setCommand(StompFrame::HeaderTypes::SEND);
     stompFrame->addHeader("destination", destination);
     stompFrame->addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
     stompFrame->addTextBody(message);
     return stompFrame;
 }

void StompDemoView::sendGreeting() {
     qDebug() << "Send greeting";
     StompFrameCreator stompFrameCreator;

     QJsonObject jsonObject;
     jsonObject.insert("name", QJsonValue::fromVariant(m_NameLineEdit->text()));
     QJsonDocument doc(jsonObject);

     auto publishFrame = stompFrameCreator.createSendTextFrame("/app/hello", doc.toJson());
     qDebug() << "Sending " << doc.toJson();
     m_StompClient.sendFrame(publishFrame);
 }

void StompDemoView::clientConnected() {
    StompFrameCreator stompFrameCreator;
    qDebug() << "Subscribe to topic";
    auto subscribeFrame = stompFrameCreator.createSubscribeFrame(0, "/topic/greetings", "auto");
    m_StompClient.sendFrame(subscribeFrame);
}
```

When the client connects to the server I am sending a subscribe request. This is being received by the server:

```
 Decoded SUBSCRIBE {id=[0], destination=[/topic/greetings], ack=[auto]} session=null
 From client: SUBSCRIBE /topic/greetings id=0 session=6cc3a2b6-48a5-1c1c-2366-d746224d60e8
 Processing SUBSCRIBE /topic/greetings id=0 session=6cc3a2b6-48a5-1c1c-2366-d746224d60e8
```

Then when a user performs a specific action in the GUI I  am sending the message to the Greeting controller which should send back a message to the subscribing client:

```
  Decoded SEND {destination=[/app/hello], content-type=[application/json]} session=null         application/json payload={
"name": "Cris"
```

}

```
  From client: SEND /app/hello session=6cc3a2b6-48a5-1c1c-2366-d746224d60e8 application/json payload={
 "name": "Cris"
```

}

```
  Searching methods to handle SEND /app/hello session=6cc3a2b6-48a5-1c1c-2366-d746224d60e8 application/json payload={
"name": "Cris"
 }
 , lookupDestination='/hello'
 Found 1 handler methods: [{[MESSAGE],[/hello]}]
 Invoking GreetingController#greeting[1 args]
 Arguments: [HelloMessage@3903b632]
 Processing return value with SendToMethodReturnValueHandler [annotationRequired=true]
 Processing MESSAGE destination=/topic/greetings session=6cc3a2b6-48a5-1c1c-2366-d746224d60e8 payload={"content":"Hello, Cris!"}
 Broadcasting to 1 sessions.
```

But I am not receiving anything on the client. I created slots for the signals binaryMessageReceived, textMessageReceived, binaryFrameReceived, textFrameReceived, errorOccured for the QWebSocket used in the communication.

Can anyone point me please in the right direction here ?

Comment: When analyzing network traffic with Wireshark I came to the conclusion that the Spring Boot server running on localhost does not send a websocket message to the client as it should.

Answer (score 0):

After using wireshark and a javascript stomp client to compare the websocket messages exchanged between the clients and the server I reached the conclusion that the Qt client did not send a CONNECT  Stomp Frame to the server. That is why the server did not send a message corresponding to the subscription, although the client had previously sent a SUBSCRIBE package.

Here is the code in the slot connect to the socketConnected slot of the QWebSocket:

```
StompFrameCreator stompFrameCreator;
auto connectFrame = stompFrameCreator.createConnectFrame("1.2", "", "", "", 10000, 10000);
m_StompClient.sendFrame(connectFrame);
```

After adding that before sending the subscription to the server, the client receives messages pertaining to the subscription from the server.